# How long does Microsoft Cognitive Services store the data of Face API after ending my subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

The data used with Face API from Microsoft Cognitive Services are being saved on Microsoft datacenters. You could see on these both links: 
http://azuredatacentermap.azurewebsites.net/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/
in which datacenters (which region) are the data being saved. 
I couldn't find anything about the ability of deleting the data (my images which are used by Face API)and how long does Microsoft keep the data! To make my self clear, here are my two questions:

**How long does Microsoft Cognitive Services store the data of Face API after ending my subscription?**

**Am I able to delete the data permanently after ending my Microsoft Cognitive Services (Face API) subscription?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello from Face Team in Microsoft,

Short answer for your two questions:

> How long does Microsoft Cognitive Services store the data of Face API
>   after ending my subscription?

Almost none, only the deletion process time. And there is also no data retention strategy currently.

> Am I able to delete the data permanently after ending my Microsoft
>   Cognitive Services (Face API) subscription?

Yes.

---

A **more formal** version of response:

> The Face API doesn’t currently offer a feature that allows images to be persisted in the service. System data that’s generated within the Face API service for individual customers, and user-provided values in “userData” fields are automatically deleted within 24 hours after their subscription ends.